# How to hide or remove the "add new" submenu when a custom input type is register in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I don't want to disable the function, I need it but I don't want to see it in the submenu

I would like to know if there is a way doing it on `wordpress` before doing anything else, I know that I can apply some css style but I'm interested to know if wordpress offers something.

This is the function where I regsier the custom input type

```
public function activate()
{
$labels =  [
  'name' => 'Email List',
  'singular_name' => 'Email List',
  'add_new' => 'Add Email'
];

$args = [
  'labels' => $labels,
  'public' => true,
  'has_archive' => false,
  'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-email-alt',
  'supports' => false,
  'exclude_from_search' => true,
  'publicly_queryable' => false,

];

register_post_type( 'surveyemail', $args );
```

}

things that I tried is, if I remove the

```
'add_new' => 'Add Email'
```

it will added by default, with the name "add new"

at the moment I just know how to rename the value

Answer (score 0):

Piece of cake all you need to do is to add below code in arguments.

```
'show_in_menu'       => false,
```

Whenever you want this post type to show turn this into true.

```
'show_in_menu'       => true,
```

Comment: problem is that it hide the menu....I dont want to hide the whole menu... just the "add new" sub menu that is added by default